# Crear botones fuera del datatable

Tags: php, datatables, symfony2, symfony3, symfony

Hola amigos estoy trabajando en cambio de version de symfony 2 a 3.4 y al trabajar con datatables ahora no me muestra los botones fuera del datatable este es el codigo.
En la version anterior:

```
public function buildDatatable(array $options = array())
{
    $this->topActions->set(
        array(
            'start_html' => '<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-3">',
            'end_html' => '<hr></div></div>',
            'actions' => array(
                array(
                    'route' => $this->router->generate('admin_artista_new'),
                    'label' => $this->translator->trans('datatables.actions.new'),
                    'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus',
                    'attributes' => array(
                        'rel' => 'tooltip',
                        'title' => $this->translator->trans('datatables.actions.new'),
                        'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                        'role' => 'button',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'route' => $this->router->generate('admin_artistas_excel'),
                    'label' => 'Generar XLS todos los artistas',
                    'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus',
                    'attributes' => array(
                        'rel' => 'tooltip',
                        'title' => $this->translator->trans('datatables.actions.new'),
                        'class' => 'btn btn-primary',
                        'role' => 'button',
                        'target' => '_blank'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )
    );
```

no se porque no funciona el $this->actions en la nueva version